# select records with pattern matching

Tags: php, mysql, regex, select-query

My table has text in searchtxt field "Mr. johan smith" and i want to search this text even if the user enters inputs like any one :-  "mrjohan" or "mr smith" or "mr johan" or "MR.johan","Nomatch word johan" etc. But the Mr. johan smith's record should be selected as a result from query. How can i search that record to matching above pattern.

So far i have tried with this query:-

```
select t.* from temp_textsearch t
where t.searchtxt  like '%UserInput%'
```

But can't success, any idea with REGEXP to do it ?

Thanks a lot ... :)

Comment: would you be okay with matching 'mr smith' or 'mr johan' or 'mr. johan' but not the others you suggested? I think the space to separate keywords is important.

Comment: Word may be any for any records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a fulltext search engine like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the SQL function FULLTEXT can be usefull :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

An other solution is to pre-process the input before using `LIKE`